# ¿Cómo creo un arreglo de un loop?

Tags: javascript, array, bucles

soy nuevo y estoy tratando de hacer un programa con relación a procesos matemáticos.
Quiero obtener un Array de un Loop for, ejemplo

```
let number = 200
for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
Crear un array con todas las i hasta 200}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método `push` de los arrays [más info aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
let number = 200
let array = [];
for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  array.push(i);
}
console.log(array);
```